# Why is this condition satisfied? (j == nElems)

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote this code to find an element in an array which is working pretty well but I do not understand how it works 100%. My question is, how come (j == nElems) when it only runs from 0 to 9? I've also noticed that the condition is satisfied outside the for loop when the search key is not found.

```
public class ArrayApp {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int nElems = 10;
        int[] arr = new int[nElems];
        int j;
        int searchKey;
        arr[0] = 77;
        arr[1] = 99;
        arr[2] = 44;
        arr[3] = 55;
        arr[4] = 22;
        arr[5] = 88;
        arr[6] = 11;
        arr[7] = 00;
        arr[8] = 66;
        arr[9] = 33;
        for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        //Find 66 in array
        searchKey = 66;
        for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == searchKey) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == nElems) {
            System.out.println("Cant find " + searchKey);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found " + searchKey + " in position " + j);
        }
        //Remove 55 from array
        searchKey = 55; // delete item with key 55
        for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++) { // look for it
            if (arr[j] == searchKey) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int k = j; k < nElems - 1; k++) { // move higher ones down
            arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
        }
        nElems--;
        for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not debugging the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++) {
    if (arr[j] == searchKey) {
        break;
    }
}
```

nElems is 10. So j < nElems will be satisfied until j reaches 10. At that point, it will exit the loop. It'll only reach that point, however, if

```
arr[j] == searchKey
```

is never satisfied (ie. the search key is not found). So what you're seeing is that the search key is never found, j is incremented up until 10, at which point the loop is exited. At this point, j == nElems.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have look at your `for` loop:

```
for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++) {
    if (arr[j] == searchKey) {
        break;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)'s what Oracle's documentation says about `for` loop:

> The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the
>   loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or
>   decrement a value.

So, in the above loop, `j` is incremented after each iteration. In the second last iteration, `j` will be `nElems-1`. It will execute the loop and increment `j` which would then make it equal to `nElems`.

As `if` condition is placed after the loop, by the time control reaches it, `j` will already be equal to `nElems` and hence, it will be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

We can attempt to simplify what this for loop means

```
for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++) {
    if (arr[j] == searchKey) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The for loop essentially breaks down to the following:

```
int j = 0;
int nElems = 10;
while(j < nElems) {
    if(arr[j] == searchKey) {
        break;
    }
    j++;
}
```

You can see that the final condition would be when j is equivalent to 10 (nElems).

Answer (score 0):

At the end of every iteration, `j` is incremented. After that, the stopping condition is tested. If that condition is true, the loop exits. Otherwise, it continues with the new value of `j`.

This means that your `for` loop runs as long as `j < nElems`. Once `j == nElems`, the `for` loop is done. Hence at the end, `j` must necessarily be equal to `nElems`; otherwise the loop will never terminate.